# DexClassLoader on Android Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm working on a project that tries to load an external library via
DexClassLoader. This worked pretty well in 2.3:

```
    public class FormularDisplayLoader {
public final static String PATH ="/data/data/at.mSystem.client/files/mSystem_Client_FormularLibrary.jar";
        private DexClassLoader classLoader;

            public FormularDisplayLoader(Context context){
                    this.context = context;
                    this.classLoader = new DexClassLoader("/data/data/at.mSystem.client/
    files/mSystem_Client_FormularLibrary.jar",
                        context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),
                        null,
                        FormularDisplayLoader.class.getClassLoader());
            }

            public View getDisplay(String className) throws ErrorCodeException{
                    try {
                            Class c = classLoader.loadClass(className);
                            Method m = c.getMethod("getDisplay", Context.class);
                            View ret = (View) m.invoke(c.newInstance(), context);
                            return ret;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            throw new
    ErrorCodeException(FormularErrorCode.NO_DISPLAY_AVAILABLE_FOR_FORMULAR);
                    }
            }

    }
```

Unfortunately, when trying to port this app to Honeycomb (because the
actual target for this app are tablets) the DexClassLoader throws an
exception:

```
02-23 09:30:58.221: ERROR/dalvikvm(8022): Can't open dex cache '/data/
dalvik-cache/
data@d...@at.mSystem.client@files@mSystem_Client_FormularLibrary....@classes.dex':
No such file or directory
02-23 09:30:58.221: INFO/dalvikvm(8022): Unable to open or create
cache for /data/data/at.mSystem.client/files/
mSystem_Client_FormularLibrary.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/
data@d...@at.mSystem.client@files@mSystem_Client_FormularLibrary....@classes.dex)
02-23 09:30:58.231: WARN/System.err(8022):
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
at.mSystem.client.formular.contract.ContractListFormularDisplay in
loader dalvik.system.DexClassLoader@40630308
02-23 09:30:58.241: WARN/System.err(8022):     at
dalvik.system.DexClassLoader.findClass(DexClassLoader.java:240)
02-23 09:30:58.241: WARN/System.err(8022):     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:548)
02-23 09:30:58.261: WARN/System.err(8022):     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:508)
02-23 09:30:58.261: WARN/System.err(8022):     at
at.mSystem.client.system.formularmodule.formular.FormularDisplayLoader.getDisplay(FormularDisplayLoader.java:
35)
```

It seems like the DexClassLoader ignores the 2th parameter
(dexOutputDir), as the value of
context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() in my example is "/data/data/
at.mSystem.client/files".

Do you have any ideas how to solve that? Or is this some kind of
honeycomb bug?

Thanks,

Roland

Comment: I don't have an answer, but just wanted to let you know that I'm experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I opened a ticket on Android's issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15893

Comment: Same day you filed it, someone from google said "Yup, internal bug 3439372.  Scheduled for an upcoming maintenance release of Honeycomb"

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I recently needed an answer to this without upgrading to Android 3.1, so I thought I would share my solution.

I used the "DexFile" class instead of the "DexClassLoader", since it allowed me to pass the output file, thus getting around the issue with the output directory being ignored.

Here's my code:

```
final File dexClasses = new File("/sdcard/dexcontainer.zip");
DexFile dexFile = DexFile.loadDex(dexClasses.getAbsolutePath(), getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/outputdexcontainer.dex", 0);

Enumeration<String> classFileNames = dexFile.entries();
while (classFileNames.hasMoreElements())
{
  String className = classFileNames.nextElement();
  dexFile.loadClass(className, classLoader);
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the change history, this should be fixed in Android 3.1.