# How to write annotations in android missing javax.annotations.processing

Tags: java, android, jar, annotations

I am trying to write custom annotations in my android project, however javax.annotations isn't included the the android build.

https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/wiki/JavaxPackages explains how to add i, but I can't track down the javax.annotations.processing jar.

Does anyone know how I can attain this jar, or a better way to write annotations in android?

Comment: Would this be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105842/java-custom-annotation-and-dynamic-loading