# Android Dynamic Layout and Code from Web

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic

I am working on a project which will have lots and lots of Layout and Code changes.
My Question is pretty simple but I don't know anything about it. Would it be possible to dynamically load content such as Source Code (Java) and XML Layout Files on a Backgroundthread and then startup another Activity with the downloaded Content (Of either/and Java File + XML Layout)?
So that you change your Code and Layout online and download it on every start of the App?

Thanks alot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load classes [dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik). But as for xml layouts that is hardly possible sobeit you are going to write your own parser and inflater. Unfortunately `LayoutInflater` can't inflate external files. This is from `LayoutInflater` documentation:

> For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser over a plain XML file at runtime; it only works with an XmlPullParser returned from a compiled resource (R.something file.)

So you are basically restricted to create all your UI from the code only.

Comment: do you know any library that handles parsing-generating layout?