# Remote loading of Android class

Tags: android, classloader, rpc, dalvik, dex

I am developing and Android app which is divided between 2 (or more) devices. One should be the server which the client should ask it to perform a process on data. Both process and data should be sent from client to server.

I wonder how to dynamically load the process (dex class?OK, any suggestions) from the client to the server.

In other words. Server knows what to do at run-time. It's a kind of RPC but the procedure itself should be send to the server.

Any Suggestions.
Thanks on advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik?rq=1

Comment: Thanks ZG-RG ... I have seen that before but it's vague for me. I need to offload some of my application to other device(s). Also I need some suggestion for how to solve the problem as a whole.