# accessing to classes of app from dex file by classloader

Tags: android, classloader, dex

I have a app that recieve  a dex file from server then save it on sdcard and load it for

doing some functions.I am loading a my app's class from my dex file as following

dex file

```
public class Main  {


    public void onCreate() 
    {
        System.out.print("------------onCreate------------");
        try {
             final ClassLoader classloader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
            final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.example.myapp.M");
            final Object myInstance  = classToLoad.newInstance();
            final Method doSomething = classToLoad.getMethod("doSomething");
            doSomething.invoke(myInstance);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

app code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            final String libPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Lib/lib.apk";
            final File tmpDir = getDir("dex", 0);
            final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
            final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.example.lib.Main");
            final Object myInstance  = classToLoad.newInstance();
            final Method doSomething = classToLoad.getMethod("onCreate");
            doSomething.invoke(myInstance);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

M class in my app

```
public class M {
public void doSomething()
{
    Log.e("doSomething", "--------------------doSomething----");
}
}
```

but it have me following error.what is wrong in my code

```
11-19 08:24:12.718: W/System.err(10867): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapp2.M" on path: .
11-19 08:24:12.738: W/System.err(10867):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
11-19 08:24:12.747: W/System.err(10867):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
11-19 08:24:12.758: W/System.err(10867):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
11-19 08:24:12.758: W/System.err(10867):    at com.example.lib.Main.onCreate(Main.java:15)
11-19 08:24:12.768: W/System.err(10867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 08:24:12.788: W/System.err(10867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 08:24:12.788: W/System.err(10867):    at com.example.myapp2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
11-19 08:24:12.798: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
11-19 08:24:12.818: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
11-19 08:24:12.828: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
11-19 08:24:12.828: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
11-19 08:24:12.828: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
11-19 08:24:12.828: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
11-19 08:24:12.828: W/System.err(10867):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-19 08:24:12.838: W/System.err(10867):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-19 08:24:12.847: W/System.err(10867):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
11-19 08:24:12.847: W/System.err(10867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-19 08:24:12.847: W/System.err(10867):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-19 08:24:12.857: W/System.err(10867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
11-19 08:24:12.898: W/System.err(10867):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
11-19 08:24:12.898: W/System.err(10867):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is ambiguous to you in message `ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path .`

Comment: "path".can I access to classes of my app from dex file by classloader.if yes how specify path for accessing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer I need change

```
final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>)classloader.loadClass("com.example.myapp.M");
```

to

```
final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>)Class.forName("com.example.myapp.M");
```

in my dex file

Comment: its strange ho wthis worked for you.You are not mentioning your .jar file path anywhere...

Comment: So if you do this, does it then load all the other classes that com.example.myapp.M needs as well (that aren't already loaded)?

Comment: Zohreh did you load class files from the SD card? Or some other External Storage Directory? I'm curious because @Swaroop said you couldn't load them from the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

See if you're following these steps.

1. Do you have the library file as an APK or a JAR containing (Classes.dex) file on the SD Card?
2. Copy the APK file into a temporary folder into your application director /data/data/your.app.name/tmp. This is important as for security reasons Android doesn't let you load something off the SD card.
3. Use `DexClassLoader` as described here -> [How to load a Java class dynamically on android/dalvik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik)
4. Use this classloader instance for loading any dynamic class files.

If you have more than 1 JAR files then merge them into a single DEX file/APK.

To convert your Java JAR file or classes into DEX you need to use the Android SDK's dx.bat. Here's a sample ANT script to do. This can also be done via Command line too with similar arguments.

```
<exec executable="dx.bat">
    <arg value="--dex" />
    <arg value="--output=${target.directory.fullpath}/${apk.name}" />
    <arg value="--positions=lines" />
    <arg path="${classes.directory.full.path}" />
</exec>
```

Comment: can i access to my app's classes from my jar file?can you explain how I can do it?

Comment: I want from a my jar file's class call a method of my app

Comment: Yes your plugged-in JAR (DEX format) files can call the methods of your application without explicitly doing anything as it must act as a Parent Class Loader.

Comment: See the constructor for `DexClassLoader` where you set the parent class loader as one of the input. 

[DexClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html).

You can get the Parent Class Loader using activity.getClassLoader() method to pass into the `DexClassLoader()` constructor

Comment: i used above code in jar file and i get that error again.what is path in error?

Answer (score 0):

@zohreh Replace the below line

```
final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
```

to

```
final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 0):

The listed answers didn't work for me. However, getting the `ClassLoader` via `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` turned out to work:

```java
final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) Class.forName("com.example.myapp.M", true, Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```