# set up different android dependencies (.jar) for a specific android version (Lollipop)

Tags: java, android, jar, dependencies, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a problem.
My App works well and the major o Android versions.
The problem is for the devices that are greater than Android Lollipop(<5.0)
The library that gives the problem is a dependencies (PushIOManager.jar)
They have released a update for this problem. But this new file doesn't work for previous versions.
Can I Have two APK?
There´s a way to get each .jar depend on the android version? one for the previous version and one .jar for the new Lollipop.
And where should I put the code?
Thanks.

Comment: You need to load jars dynamically. There is workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik