# how to add code component to android app at runtime

Tags: android

Let's say my app has 2 features - text messaging & video calling.
I published the apk with only the text messaging feature built into it and a download button that says "Download Video Calling feature", on clicking this button the code for the video feature gets downloaded and installed which changes the current UI and displays a new video calling feature.

Is this runtime addition to code possible or do we need to build a complete new apk with both features and ask user to update from play store?
I wonder if we can do something like chrome extensions on android.

Comment: Runtime addition is not possible. You will have to give an app update. Better if you publish it with both features and the user can activate the feature when he/she wants.

Comment: Create separate (video feature) apk and use Intent to boot it (or back to another one).

Comment: Runtime addition is possible, but difficult. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022454/how-to-load-a-java-class-dynamically-on-android-dalvik?lq=1 . And this maybe interesting. "APK Expansion files" http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html