# how to load class from one another application in android

Tags: java, android, classloader

is there anyway to load a class from differen application ?

for example, I have two application and one of them has SomeExample class file. and I want to load it and use from another application.

I try to use, Class.forName. but this function throws "ClassNotFoundExpetion".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there anyway to load a class from differen application ?

No, sorry.

You can use `startActivity()`, `startService()`, and so on to launch components of another application, but each application's code remains separate.

Comment: In some cases, it seems to be possible (the target APK would have to be world-readable) - see my answer and the reference. It's almost certainly not a good idea, though.

Answer (score 1):

While in most cases unadvisable (Android has many APIs to solve the common problems of inter-app communication without sharing code), it's [possible](http://www-jo.se/f.pfleger/apk-piracy) by using [PathClassLoader](http://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/PathClassLoader.html).

See also [Android- Using DexClassLoader to load apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903260/android-using-dexclassloader-to-load-apk-file).