# Plugin system with DexClassLoader() and user interface

Tags: android, dexclassloader

For a long-term student project, i'm trying to develop a modular application with plugins. Specifically, we would have:

- A master application where we could search, update, delete and run the plugins. This master application would also store some data from plugins.
- Several plugins downloaded from a HTTP server with code and GUI components.

For now, i have a master application which is able to download a .apk file from HTTP and to create a new instance from a class defined in this .apk file. I use the way described here: http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html with the DexClassLoader() method.

But i'm unable to see how to display a layout (or any other GUI component) stored as a resource in the plugin .apk file. For instance, i tried without success to create an Intent from the master application by using the plugin classname:

```
DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(...);
Class<?> libClass = cl.loadClass("plugin_classname");
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), libClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

And this doesn’t work because the Intent is not declared in the AndroidManifest.xml of the master application. This is also described in this other thread: [Android- Using DexClassLoader to load apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903260/android-using-dexclassloader-to-load-apk-file)

Does that mean that there is absolutely no way to build a such "dynamic" user interface?  More generally, can this type of plugin system be done on Android? Should i try an other method?

Comment: rather than making the Activity dynamic, always use the same activity and use the DexClassLoader to load a fragment instead.

Comment: How did you build you `plugin.jar`. The jar that implements the interface? I have a jar built by eclipse with `classes.dex` entry but the `loadClass` always throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

**I once tried the same thing and found it impossible.** If the basic mechanism has not been changed since then (Jan. 2011), it is still impossible. Technical details are described in my blog in both Japanese and English.

Blog: **Dynamically add an Activity that is not declared in AndroidManifest.xml (impossible)**
http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.jp/2011/01/androidmanifestxml-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

See this answer. It is about how to dynamically run Android's 'Activity', 'Service', which did not declared in AndroidManifest.xml, at runtime: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41112682/2801776