# Is app cloning on Android similar to running a mini-VM, does it create a pseudo-OS?

Tags: android

I am curious about the technical details of how app cloning (dual apps on MIUI) works. From what I understand it creates a folder with a second installation of the app, but how does it "fool" the server side of the app to show a different installation/device? **Does it work as a VM or is it some kind of simplified VM?**

Does it spoof the MAC address, device ID, installation ID? Can someone explain the technicalities of it for someone who is not an Android programmer?

Comment: See: https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/17/droidception.html and related SO post: [How to execute APKs on a customized data directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41570178/295004)

Comment: @MorrisonChang interesting stuff thanks for the links, but way too technical for someone without Android background. Still doesn't answer my questions.

Comment: Not sure what question you are asking then as it could cover anything from: how do Virtual Machines/Emulators work, what is a Man-In-The-Middle attack/proxy, and/or how can servers detect compromised client apps. You should edit your question with the one particular point of confusion.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I have asked the question in the title, if app cloning is the same as running a VM.

Comment: I thought that your question was answered in the link to the post by Commonsware. Perhaps you should explain what your definition of `VM` vs `simplified VM` is. There is no hypervisor in the droidception (so not a true VM). Arguably it could be considered an emulator or perhaps a container as it is a 1-to-1 API to Android OS.